Evento diario de mysql solo se ejecuta una sola vez
He ejecutado un evento que deseo que sea diario y a una hora específica, pero solo se ejecuta una sola vez... Este es el script que ejecuté en phpmayadmin:
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT reset_capacidad_disponible
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2024-08-01 23:59:59'
DO
BEGIN
    UPDATE empleados
    SET capacidad_disponible = capacidad_horas;
END$$
DELIMITER ;


También ejecuté esto:
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
Ejecuté esto, y me devolvió ON:
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'event_scheduler';
Además estoy en Windows 10 y he modificado el my.ini de xampp, ahora se ve así:
[mysqld]
port=3306
event_scheduler=ON --añadí esto

No he apagado el servicio de mysql, esperé dos días y solo se ejecutó una vez. También cambié la fecha para acelerar el proceso, pero solo funcionó la primera vez, ¿qué pasa y cómo se puede solucionar? Porque necesito que se ejecute a diario esta actualización. Gracias.

STARTS '2024-08-01 23:59:59' ... No ha transcurrido un dia todavia. Deja el evento programado y verifica mañana día 3 si se ha ejecutado o no. Hoy estamos a 2 y no son todavía las 23:59:59. O si quieres ponle un intervalo de tiempo menor para fines de prueba. Aparte de eso, ¿qué se supone que haga el UPDATE y de dónde tomaría los datos para hacer la actualización?

Ya pasó un día y no se ejecutó la actualización, probé con intervalos más cortos pero solo se ejecuta una sola vez. Con respecto a la funcionalidad del update, este actualiza la capacidad disponible de un empleado a la capacidad total que se ha configurado, por ejemplo si un empleado trabaja 6 horas, el programa debe setear esta cantidad todos los días a capacidad_disponible, pues este campo disminuye con el paso del día

Vea el siguiente dbfiddle para ideas.

El valor en STARTS debe ser un momento en el futuro. Si el evento ya se ejecutó, el evento no volverá a ejecutarse hasta que se vuelva a crear o se modifique.
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE EVENT reset_capacidad_disponible
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY -- Comienza mañana a la misma hora
    DO
    BEGIN
        UPDATE empleados
        SET capacidad_disponible = capacidad_horas;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;

Podes checkear si quedo ok haciendo esta consulta:
SHOW EVENTS;

